# Connection between Hadoop and informix using Sqoop

Tags: hadoop, connection, informix, sqoop

I am trying do connection between informix and Hadoop, I found following connection string in IBM website but stuck with errors. Can anyone help me to modify the following code:

```
sqoop list-tables --driver com.informix.jdbc.IfxDriver \
--connect "jdbc:informix-sqli://host:port/dbname:INFORMIXSERVER=server;user=rrr;Password=rrr1"
```

Answer (score 0):

From `scoop` documentation I see that you can use `--username` and `--password` arguments instead of trying to include it into JDBC connect string.

At first you must be sure your connect string is correct. You must talk with DB administrator and fill `host`, `port`, `dbname` and `server` parts of your connect string. In my case such connect string looks like:

```
jdbc:informix-sqli://test-informix:9088/testdb:informixserver=ol_testifx;DB_LOCALE=pl_PL.CP1250;CLIENT_LOCALE=pl_PL.CP1250;charSet=CP1250
```

Its parts are described in documentation: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v111/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.jdbc_pg.doc/sii-02conect-15069.htm

There is optional username and password but I think it will be safer to use it in separate `scoop` arguments